# How i do check if record exists in variable then verify form input with variable record

Tags: php

Have this code i want to check if record exist in **$pas** before processing result
 then try to verify **$pas** by form input
I have tried this:

```
$pas = "1234";
$text = "12345678910111213141516";
if(empty($pas)) {
    echo $text;
}
else
{
    if (isset($_POST["subscribe"]))
    {
        $phone = $_POST["phone"];
        if ($phone == $pas)
        {
            echo $text;
        }
        else
        {
            if ($phone != "$pass")
            {
                echo erro;
            }
        }
    } 
}
if(!isset($_POST["phone"]) || $_POST["phone"] != $pas)
{
    echo '<form action="#" method="POST">
        Your Phone Number <br /> 
        <input type="text" name="phone" value="080"/>
        <input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="SEND PAYMENT"/>
        </form>';
}
```

But I get result even when 'pas' is not there what am I doing Wrong?

Comment: where you want to check??

Comment: is this related to a mysql database?

Comment: What’s the difference between this, and your previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377332/how-do-i-verify-form-input-before-displaying-record ?

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, that's what I was asking myself also.

Comment: `"$pass"` please dont do stuff like that. Use `$pass` as is, since using quotes around it doesnt do anything here except using more memory. That is because strings in double quotes get interpreted (dont know if interpreted is the right term here).

Comment: what do you mean by this? *"How i do check if record exist in querry"* - db query? Your question's unclear.

Comment: Note: I did an edit of your question, proper indentation is critical.  Look the answer from pr1nc3, he modified a } closure.  Without indentation, it is hard to read your code.

Comment: [This is a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard#comment526922_358600) in a [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358600/1415724) that was created for posts just like this.

Comment: Thank you for your ever so lovely cooperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$pas = "1234";
$text = "12345678910111213141516";
if(empty($pas)) {
    echo $text;
}
else
{
    if (isset($_POST["subscribe"]))
    {
        $phone = $_POST["phone"];
        if ($phone == $pas)
        {
            echo $text;
        }
        else
        {
            if ($phone != "$pass")
            {
                echo erro;
            }
        }
    }

if(!isset($_POST["phone"]) || $_POST["phone"] != $pas)
{
    echo '<form action="#" method="POST">
 Your Phone Number <br /> 
 <input type="text" name="phone" value="080"/>
  <input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="SEND PAYMENT"/>
 </form>';
}
}
```

Your else bracket was closing sooner than you wanted so your `echo` would be executed anyway as it was outside of your `if/else`